# ClearCase Migration (Windows domain)

Tags: clearcase

We are in the process of migrating our ClearCase environment from one windows domain to another windows domain. Host name will rename the same only fully dns name will change.

Believe renaming a license server host does not invalidate the license; License depends on hardware-level machine identifier, not its network host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed what the ClearCase page "[Renaming a license server host](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_licadm_cc_rename_host.htm)"

You would still need to follow "[Moving licenses to another host](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_licadm_cc_mv_license.htm)"